# how to set position of WPF in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xbap

I wrote a program in WPF via using Visual Studio and my program works perfectly.When I publish it, it seems like the image below on internet explorer.I just want to see my app on top.

This is my current view
[image: This is my current view]
This is what I want
[image: This is what I want]

Page1.XML

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

Title="Page1">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="stackPanel" 

       HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

Page1.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using BenzinTakip;

namespace WPFHost
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        private readonly Form1 mainForm = new Form1();

        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Create a Windows Forms Host to host a form
            WindowsFormsHost windowsFormsHost = new WindowsFormsHost();

            mainForm.TopLevel = false;

            windowsFormsHost.Child = mainForm;

            stackPanel.Children.Add(windowsFormsHost);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your Form1 class defined?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the web page this is presented in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of your resolution you have to change your form's dimensions and it will fit.

Comment: I've already did it and it fixed my problem anyway thanks your answer

Comment: If it fixed so wrote here because your question seems unanswered

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code below in your `<StackPanel>` tag on the `Page1.xml` side of your code.

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="StackPanelMargining" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
     </Style>
     <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource StackPanelMargining}" TargetType="Your Target Element"/>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your asking.

If you want your window to be above all other windows on the OS you can use the IsTopMost=true parameter.

If you want one element on your window to be shown above something else this is the Z-Order. In WPF the Z-Order is defined by the order the elements appear in your XAML. For instance if you create a button, then an image the image would be placed above the button, because the image is defined further down in the XAML.